# Is it possible to disallow 'null' for either one of two variables at the migration level?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, migration, rails-migrations

`Author` belongs to either an article or a book and never both. In the migration file for Author I have:

```
t.references :article, index: true
t.references :book,    index: true
```

In the model file:

```
  validate :article_or_book_id

  def article_or_book_id
    if article_id.present? && book_id.present?
      errors.add(:article_id, "An author has to have either a book or article")
    elsif !article_id.present? && !book_id.present?
      errors.add(:article_id, "This author has no article nor a book")
    end
  end
```

Question: How can I add to the migration file that either `:article` or `:book` cannot be `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `polymorphic association`?

Here is the tutorial:

[polymorphic association](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association)

Comment: Thanks, that indeed looks like what I need.

Comment: I was hoping to ask a small follow-up question. In the `Author` migration file I have `t.references :authorsource, polymorphic: true, index: true`. I understand this creates `authorsource_id` and `authorsource_type`. The `index` makes that `authorsource_id` cannot be `null`. But what about `authorsource_type`? I guess that cannot be `null` either, right? (which is what I want, since an `Author` has to have a source).

Comment: Yup, you should get the index with a combination of `id` and `type`